# How to hold the selected value in the radio button?

Tags: android, radio-button, store

I'M doing quiz app. I have set 50 questions and each question contains 4 options(radio group) with pervious and next button. What i need is when select the answer and goes for next question and again he comes to previous question that time what he select perviously that answer should be in selected state.
But user selected value i getText()
How to implement this ?  Any one help me..

Thanks in advance..

```
ImageView previousbtn1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.prv_btn);
        previousbtn1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if ( j < 1 )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Question.this, "First Question", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    --j;
                    --num;
                    --m;
                    TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt);
                    txtque.setText("Q" + num + ")" + ques1.get(j));
                    --k;
                    btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get((k * 4) + 0));
                    btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get((k * 4) + 1));
                    btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get((k * 4) + 2));
                    btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get((k * 4) + 3));
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: save your question number as key ans selected rediobutton as value in shareprefrance. when its back to privios ans then just fetch from shareprefrance. set radiobutton selected.

Comment: @sankar help me how to do this?

Comment: @dhavalsodhaparmar can give example code for me.

Comment: here is code with checkbox: http://turing.cs.trincoll.edu/~ram/cpsc110/tutorials/quizapp/

Comment: check Marko Niciforovic answer

Answer (score 1):

Basically it looks like your problem is not how to set a radio button active, but the whole concept - so I describe how I'd do it:

**The easy way**

Use any kind of list or map (preferably hashmap, where the key is the question number and the value is the answer value (1,2 or 3 - simple integers)). Then when you're at question 2 for example, you check if there is alrerady an entry for the key 2, if so you you read out the value and actviate the corresponding radio button (this is by the way done with `radio1.setChecked(true)`) - if not as soon as the user clicks a radio button the anser is stored in the hash map.

**The maybe better way :)**

Almost same as before, but instead of simple "ints" as answers you use objects for your answers (maybe also for the questions, then you could store your answers directly in the question) - this is good if the answers / questions are gonna be more complicated then simple "1,2 or 3".

**Side note**

If the answers of the users should be available AFTER the app is closed, you'd have to store them in either a sqlite db or in shared preferences. I think sqlite is better for this, since these ansers are not really SharedPreferences/Settings, but you surely need a little more effort.

---

Since you ask for it:

```
switch(answer){
    case 1:
        radio1.setChecked(true)
    break;
    case 2:
        radio2.setChecked(true)
    break;
    case 3:
        radio3.setChecked(true)
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: I can't understand your answ frnd..My problem is when i comes to perivous question what i selected that option should be in selected state that should not clear How to do this..

Comment: answer is good, he is saying you to save the state of all 50 question in some array/map, then whenever you open a particular question, fetch the value from the array, set the radiotext active

Answer (score 1):

use SharedPreferences, that will save your values permanently, untill user reinstall (clear data) application. Shared Preferences works like this

```
// save string in sharedPreferences
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("some_key", string); // here string is the value you want to save
                    editor.commit();                    

// restore string in sharedPreferences 
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
string = settings.getString("some_key", "");
```

Comment: Its working but if i have 9 quest and goes to 9 quest and come to 8 quest, its answer showing and if i come 7, 6, 5... its the 8 quest answer for all 5,6,7....